# What is "88-type" in C# and how can i use it?

Tags: c#, .net, calculator, operator-keyword

I've got a Task to program a C# Consolecalculator.

My problem is that I don't what "88-type" is and how to use it. I had to use it to guarantee that the user only can use `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.

The following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gmaare_consolen_rechner_1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jaNein, rechenzeichen;

            do {
                int zahl_1 = Convert.ToInt32(null);
                zahl_1 = (Fehlerklasse.fehlerzahl_1(zahl_1));

                rechenzeichen = Console.ReadLine();

                int zahl_2 = Convert.ToInt32(null);
                zahl_2 = (Fehlerklasse.fehlerzahl_2(zahl_2));

                var ergebnis = Ergebnis.rechenmethode(zahl_1, zahl_2, rechenzeichen);
                Console.WriteLine(ergebnis);


                Console.WriteLine("Möchten sie erneut eine Rechnung stellen ? (ja / nein)");
                do
                {
                    jaNein = Console.ReadLine();  
                    if (!(jaNein == "ja" | jaNein == "nein"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Antwort, bitte wählen sie (ja / nein)");
                    }
                }
                while (!(jaNein == "ja" | jaNein == "nein"));

                Console.Clear();
            }
            while (jaNein == "ja");
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gmaare_consolen_rechner_1._0
{
    class Rechner
    {
        Fehlerklasse fehlerbehen = new Fehlerklasse();

        public int plus(int zahl_1, int zahl_2)
        {
            return zahl_1 + zahl_2;
        }

        public int minus(int zahl_1, int zahl_2)
        {
            return zahl_1 - zahl_2;
        }

        public int mal(int zahl_1, int zahl_2)
        {
            return zahl_1 * zahl_2;
        }

        public int geteiltdurch(int zahl_1, int zahl_2)
        {
            if(zahl_2!= 0)
            {
                return zahl_1 / zahl_2;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Die Division durch 0 ist verboten!");
                return zahl_2;
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gmaare_consolen_rechner_1._0
{
    class Ergebnis
    {
        public static int rechenmethode(int zahl_1, int zahl_2, string rechenzeichen)
        {
            var ergebnis = 0;

            Rechner rechnen = new Rechner();

            switch (rechenzeichen)
            {
                case "+":
                    ergebnis = rechnen.plus(zahl_1, zahl_2);

                    break;
                case "-":
                     ergebnis = rechnen.minus(zahl_1, zahl_2);

                    break;
                case "*":
                     ergebnis = rechnen.mal(zahl_1, zahl_2);

                    break;
                case "/":
                    ergebnis = rechnen.geteiltdurch(zahl_1, zahl_2);
                    break;
            }

            return ergebnis;
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gmaare_consolen_rechner_1._0
{
    class Fehlerklasse
    {
        public static int fehlerzahl_1(int zahl_1)
        {
            bool tryAgain = true;
            while (tryAgain)
            {
                try
                {
                    zahl_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    tryAgain = false;
                }
                catch (FormatException)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Geben sie eine gültige Zahl ein!");
                }
                catch (OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Die Zahl ist zu gross, geben sie eine gültige Zahl ein!");
                }
            }
            return zahl_1;
        }

        public static int fehlerzahl_2(int zahl_2)
        {
            bool tryAgain = true;
            while (tryAgain)
            {
                try
                {
                    zahl_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    tryAgain = false;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Geben sie eine gültige Zahl ein!");
                }
                catch (Exception )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Die Zahl ist zu gross, geben sie eine gültige Zahl ein!");
                }
            }
            return zahl_2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the magic `88` type?  I don't see it.  (My German comprehension is bad, but it's not _that_ bad.) The only `type-88` that know about is either a Chinese main battle tank, or a Chinese sniper rifle.  Also please read [mcve] and think about how to reduce the code to the minimum required to produce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: The only meaning I know of for 88 is one of the 3rd Reich, which I doubt you mean.

Comment: Maybe the task is to emulate a TI-88 calculator? There's also a Casio 88. 
http://www.datamath.org/Sci/Slanted/TI-88.htm
http://www.casio-europe.com/euro/calc/tax/ms88eco/

Comment: Is this related to the german idiom "egal ist 88"? Roughly translated "88 doesn't matter". Meaning it doesn't matter how you look at 88, it always looks the same (draw both eights on a piece of paper close together and rotate it in 90° intervals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too guarantee that the user can use the operators +,-,*,/ right?.
My suggestion is that you add a method in your "Fehlerklasse" to check the operator(Rechenzeichen).

```
   public static string fehlerrechenzeichen(string rechenzeichen)
    {
        bool tryAgain = true;
        while (tryAgain)
        {
            try
            {
                rechenzeichen = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (rechenzeichen)
                {
                    case "+":
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new FormatException("Geben sie eine gültiges Rechenzeichen ein!");
                }
                tryAgain = false;
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return rechenzeichen;
    }
```